# Bookdown: Produce only PDF, no HTML

Tags: r, bookdown

I have a large bookdown project. My YAML header below.

My only desired output is a PDF. However, bookdown by default produces a HTML as well. This makes compilation take more time, and also uses more caching space on my disk. Any chance I can disable producing HTML output? I have tried to play around with the `site` parameter in the YAML heading, but no luck.

```
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: 
- "Name"
- "Institution" 
date: "September 2020"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: natbib
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [references.bib] 
biblio-style: "apalike"
geometry: "left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
```

Comment: bookdown doesn't really have a default output format. If it produces HTML, the output format must have been provided somewhere. Check if you have a `_output.yml` under the root directory of your book project. If you do, delete it.

Comment: Great, that's what I needed. Feel free to make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bookdown** doesn't really have a "default" output format. If it produces HTML, the output format must have been provided somewhere. Check if you have a `_output.yml` under the root directory of your book project. If you do, you may delete it. Then **bookdown** will use the `output` field that you specified in the YAML frontmatter of your `Rmd` document.